# mongodb, get the related documents from an array

Tags: mongodb, reference

I have an `Event` collection that could contain the following:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a12fa490eeff735737e7711"), 
  "title" : "dgdfgfgfd", 
  "startDate" : ISODate("2017-11-20T15:52:33.060Z"), 
  "endDate" : ISODate("2017-11-20T16:52:33.060Z"), 
  "registrations" : [ ObjectId("5a0c0c5ea8c2405f092fc83d") ] 
}
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a12ffbed7a6043de1ba7d72"), 
  "title" : "kjkj", 
  "startDate" : ISODate("2017-11-20T16:15:54.204Z"), 
  "endDate" : ISODate("2017-11-20T16:15:54.204Z"), 
  "registrations" : [ ObjectId("5a0c0c5ea8c2405f092fc83d"), ObjectId("7a0c0c5ea8dfd05f092fc84d") ]
}
```

The `registration` field contains a set of user ids.

How to get a list of all users referenced in `registrations` for a given event?

For instance, for event with _id `5a12fa490eeff735737e7711` I would like to end up with a list of users that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a0c0c5ea8c2405f092fc83d"), 
    "name" : "test user"
    "email" : "m@m.fr"
  }
]
```

In this case, there would be only one element in the resulting list since the `registrations` field for the given event only contains a single reference.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The aggregation is not so trivial so maybe you should consider embedding these two fields into your array (also because of potential performance issues). However, what you need to do is to:

- unwind registrations
- use $lookup to join data from second collection
- use $project to decompose your document, so that registration id and data about users will be one subdocument
- use $group to obtain array of registrations

  ```
  db.Event.aggregate([
     {
         "$unwind": "$registrations"
     },
     {
        "$lookup": {
           "from": "Users",
           "localField": "registrations",
           "foreignField": "_id",
           "as" : "user"
           }
     },
     {
        "$project": {
           "_id": 1,
           "title" : 1,
           "startDate" : 1,
           "endDate": 1,
           "registrations._id": "registrations",
           "registrations.name": "user.name",
           "registrations.email": "user.email" 
         }
     },
     {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "title" : { "$first": "$title"},
            "startDate" : { "$first": "$startDate"}, 
            "endDate" : { "$first": "$endDate"},
            "registrations": { "$push": "$registrations"}
         }
      }
  ```

  ])